# Single responsibility principle - Is it bad to use a single access point for all classes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, architecture, solid-principles

I am making a game, in this game I have units. I used to just have one big class called `Unit` which did more or less everything, which is bad.

So I split it up into several classes, `UnitSelectable`, `UnitAnimator`, `UnitDetection`, `UnitAi`, `UnitHealth`, `UnitDataContainer`, and so on...

Now to the problem, I am using a State Machine where I want states to be quite generic, so they just take a parameter `(Unit unit)`, then I can do whatever I want in the State using this. But now that I have a ton of classes managing the behaviour of a Unit, so what do I pass to my State? What if I want to do something in the state that needs `UnitAnimator` and `UnitHealth`?

So to my question, *would it be bad to create a class `Unit` that simply holds a reference to all other classes above, then I can pass that `Unit` to my state machine and do whatever I want in there?*

Comment: It might be a subjective subject, but your question reminds me the [Facade Design Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/facade)

Comment: If you are using Unity - this is exactly why it has Components: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Components.html

Comment: @Milney Not sure what you mean. I could make each class here a component, sure, but then I'd be stucck calling GetComponent<> each time I want to do something, which is awful...

Comment: @Green_qaue - why is that awful? It decouples the Unit class (or GameObject) from its behaviours, which allows dynamically changing those behaviours, and means interacting code doesn't need to know up front if a behavior exists. It literally was designed to address this problem, and is used in many large games successfully. If you do it your way you are *stuck* referencing them through variables, which means you can't change the number or shape of behaviours dynamically?

Comment: @Milney So you mean I pass GameObject or Transform to my states, and simply use GetComponent<> once in the State?
It's not the worst Idea actually, since I could just cache the components I need in OnEnter in the State, then use that in OnUpdate. This would also mean I can use the same StateMachine for any GameObject, not just Units.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what a Unit is in your context, but what about to make your `Unit*` classes implementing a common interface ( as they are all units probably, and they share some common behavior I assume because of their name) and then pass a parameter of the `Unit` interface to your State? If you do that you can implement the behavior using polymorphism avoiding conditional code.

***"would it be bad to create a class Unit that simply holds a reference to all other classes above..."***

Your approach is basically the `Mediator` pattern where you encapsulate how a set of objects interact, keeping your objects from referring to each other explicitly (in your case the `Unit` class would hold the references of all the communicating objects). This is not a bad approach at all because you decouple the specific classes from each other, but you have to keep in mind that the `Unit` class will need to be very intimate with all the different classes, and become really complex (making it hard to maintain).

The best solution from my perspective would be to derive all your `Unit*` classes from a common interface and so your State machine would just call the appropriate actions polymorphically, but I understand this is not always possible, so going with a `Unit` Mediator object is another possible solution.